# Adding XAMPP SQL database to PhpStorm gives rejected details error

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, phpstorm, lamp

I've installed XAMPP and am running the built in SQL server, but for some reason whenever I try to test the connection of the XAMPP default (test) database through PhpStorm it comes up with an error message of:

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone.

I haven't changed any settings in phpMyAdmin in XAMPP or anything i've left all settings as default. I followed some video tutorials on YouTube and they didn't get this error.

I can create databases and tables fine in phpMyAdmin with no username or password so i'm not sure what the issue is.

Any help will be appreciated

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known problem with latest JDBC drivers, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7727.  Workarounds:

- In DataSource configuration window go to Advanced tab and set `serverTimezone` property to `UTC`.
- Switch DataSource driver to MySQL Connector/J for 5.1 (my version is 5.1.46)

Comment: That works great, I managed to create a table from within PhpStorm in the test database, and I can see the created table in phpMyAdmin. However for some reason when I click the little arrow to the left of my database connection within the PhpStorm database window, I can't see any scemeas or tables, only bin and ci files. Have you any idea why that could be?

Comment: Check this one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/cannot-find-a-database-object-in-the-database-tree-view.html#step-2-verify-that-the-necessary-schemas-are-selected